# Two digital pins for reading buttons, writing to RST

Tags: microcontroller, diodes, esp8266, input, button

I have an ESP8266 with two buttons connected to pulled-up GPIO4 and GPIO14. The buttons pull the signal down if pressed. I want to reset the microcontroller on every raising edge. I thought about adding two diodes, so that the readings of one button don't get messed up by another button. The buttons are pulled up by internal resistors in the code.
But my circuit doesn't seem to do what I wanted:
[image]

What it should do:
The two buttons are in a case. When one of them is pressed, the ESP wakes up from deep sleep. It then reads the values on GPIOs and sends them via WiFi. After that it listens for a falling edge (via interrupt) on those two GPIOs and restarts in software and then goes to sleep if the buttons are pressed down. So it's in deep sleep with a low signal on RST, if I release the button RST goes high and the ESP wakes up.

Comment: So what does the circuit do and what did you want it to do? Yes, pushing either button will bring RST down.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, @Justme! I included additional information.

Comment: Add a pull-up to RST?

Comment: Oh I forgot to draw it, there is a pull-up resistor on RST

Comment: But if pulling RST low puts ESP to reset until you release a button, and it takes a while for the ESP to boot and run the code to read IO pins, how could the ESP ever see any buttons being pushed? Or is there something wrong with my assumption how the RST pin works?

Comment: ESP8266 RST is active low. Maybe this link is helpful: https://circuits4you.com/2016/12/14/reset-programming-esp8266/

Comment: @Justme Only after the low signal goes high, the ESP reboots

Comment: The datasheet says reset pin is active low. Are you sure it only resets on rising edge?

Comment: @Justme yes, I tested the circuit with only one button and it worked without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Probably what’s happening is that when the button is released, by the time RESET completes and the code starts the GPIO state is gone. You’ll need to hold the GPIO state long enough so your program can read it. Perhaps add some R-C delay?